# Dependency injection in Apache Ignite.NET service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ignite

Consider Apache Ignite.NET cluster that provides service grid.

There is a simple service, that will run on any node:

```
public class ClientConnectionService : IClientConnectionService, IService
{
    private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    [InstanceResource] private IIgnite Ignite { get; set; }

    public void Listen(string hostname, int port, uint username, string password,
        ClientConnectionListenerOptions options = ClientConnectionListenerOptions.All)
    {
        Logger.Debug("Listen");
    }

    public void Init(IServiceContext context)
    {
        Logger.Debug("Initialized");
    }

    public void Execute(IServiceContext context)
    {
        Logger.Debug("Executed");
    }

    public void Cancel(IServiceContext context)
    {
        Logger.Debug("Canceled");
    }
}
```

The application is using Castle Windsor as inversion of control container.

I would like to inject custom dependencies, that won't be serialized and transferred over the wire.

Is there any way to achieve it?

N.B. In Java version, there is `@SpringResource`annotation that will basically do what I want, but the question is about .NET, that provides just `[InstanceResource]` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I have ended up with:

1. In shared project where all the interfaces and contracts are described I've introduced IContainer

```cs
    public interface IContainer
    {
        T Resolve<T>();
    }
```

2. In project that is responsible for Apache Ignite.NET integration I've implemented simple Apache Ignite.NET plugin

```cs
    public class DependencyInjectionPlugin
    {
        public IContainer Container { get; set; }

        public T Resolve<T>()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<T>();
        }
    }

    [PluginProviderType(typeof(DependencyInjectionPluginProvider))]
    public class DependencyInjectionPluginConfiguration : IPluginConfiguration
    {
        public void WriteBinary(IBinaryRawWriter writer)
        {
            // No-op
        }

        public int? PluginConfigurationClosureFactoryId { get; } = null; // No Java part
    }

    public class DependencyInjectionPluginProvider : IPluginProvider<DependencyInjectionPluginConfiguration>
    {
        public string Name { get; } = "DependencyInjection";

        public string Copyright { get; } = "MIT";

        protected DependencyInjectionPlugin DependencyInjectionPlugin { get; set; }

        public T GetPlugin<T>() where T : class
        {
            return DependencyInjectionPlugin as T;
        }

        public void Start(IPluginContext<DependencyInjectionPluginConfiguration> context)
        {
            DependencyInjectionPlugin = new DependencyInjectionPlugin();
        }

        public void Stop(bool cancel)
        {

        }

        public void OnIgniteStart()
        {

        }

        public void OnIgniteStop(bool cancel)
        {

        }
    }
```

3. In main project, that is responsible for wiring up all components, I've implemented IContainer, defined previously, and registered it in Castle Windsor:

```cs
    public class DependencyInjectionContainer : IContainer
    {
        protected IKernel Kernel { get; set; }

        public DependencyInjectionContainer(IKernel kernel)
        {
            Kernel = kernel;
        }

        public T Resolve<T>()
        {
            return Kernel.Resolve<T>();
        }
    }

    public class DependencyInjectionInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component
                    .For<IContainer>()
                    .ImplementedBy<DependencyInjectionContainer>()
            );
        }
    }
```

4. In the very same project I've registered Apache Ignite.NET

```cs
    public class IgniteInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component
                    .For<IIgnite>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => Ignition.Start(new IgniteConfiguration
                    {
                        PluginConfigurations = new[] {new DependencyInjectionPluginConfiguration()}
                    }))
            );
        }
    }
```

5. Finally, in application's main method:

```cs
    // Build Windsor container
    using (var container = new WindsorContainer())
    {
        // Install DI abstraction layer
        container.Install(new DependencyInjectionInstaller());

        // Install cluster abstraction layer
        container.Install(new IgniteInstaller());

        // Attach DI container to cluster plugin
        container
            .Resolve<IIgnite>()
            .GetPlugin<DependencyInjectionPlugin>("DependencyInjection")
            .Container = container.Resolve<IContainer>();

        // Wait
        Done.Wait();
    }
```

That's it. From now on, I am able to access IContainer implementation in Apache Ignite.NET distributed service like this:

```cs
    var plugin = Ignite.GetPlugin<DependencyInjectionPlugin>("DependencyInjection");
    var whatever = plugin.Resolve<IWhatever>();
```

Comment: Big thanks for posting this solution. I just started to think that plugins may be a workaround here. We at Ignite definitely need to think of a better DI/IoC support.

Comment: Thank you, this has really helped me resolve a similar problem!

Comment: Thanks for this pattern. I ended up creating a service locator in .net core may convert it to a proper container